# Maven Dependency Plugin - Get with dependency mediation on artifacts with jre specific versioning

Tags: maven

I'm trying to download jars from maven using the maven dependency plugin which provides the [get](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) mojo. I want to get the latest version that is higher than 7.4 and lower than 8.0. This is all fine as I can use [dependency mediation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution#DependencyMediationandConflictResolution-DependencyVersionRanges) `[7.4,8.0)` as the version number in the command:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:get -Dartifact=com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:[7.4,8.0)
```

This is working just great, except actually I want to get the jre8 version of the jar, but it's downloading the jre12 version as naturally 12 > 8.

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:get -
Dartifact=com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:[7.4,8.0)
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:get (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Resolving com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:[7.4,8.0) with transitive dependencies
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/7.4.1.jre12/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/7.4.1.jre12/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.pom (18 KB at 72.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/7.4.1.jre12/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/7.4.1.jre12/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar (1191 KB at 4078.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.499 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-07-23T14:07:29+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/372M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to specify to get the jre8 version whilst retaining the version mediation?